# Use Datable with Nodejs socket.io

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, socket.io, datatables

I'm currently starting using Datatables (https://datatables.net) to create tables.

The data in the table are obtained through socket.io from the server.

My problem is when socket.io add data, the table isn't "updated", it says it only have 1 entry and search box is only working on the last element added.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
    socket.on('jobStepsResponse', function(message) {
            document.getElementById('listOfJobs').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('contentJob').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('jobid').innerHTML = "<button onClick=returnToJobList()>Retour</button>  Job "+message.idJob;
            for(var i=0;i<Object.keys(message.status).length;i++){
                document.getElementById('tabstats').innerHTML += '<tr><td>'+Object.keys(message.status)[i]+'</td>'+'<td>'+ts2time(message.status[Object.keys(message.status)[i]])+'</td>'+'</tr>';
            }
            $(document).ready(function() {$('#example2').DataTable();} );
            setInterval( function () { $('#example2').DataTable().ajax.reload( null, false ); }, 1000 );
        });
```

As you can see, I tried using ajax reload but i think its for ajax data sources, so it doesn't work.

Comment: why you added $(document).ready in jobsteps.. event

Comment: originally to load datatable style upon socket but since it is $document.ready, it is not useful there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, i wait for table to be fully populated first, the call the Datatables style which will count all the element added.

Only problem is that it show the unformatted datas for some times so you need to add a DOM control to show a loading thing for example.